# jquery code not working the code is perfect don't know what is wrong

Tags: jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("p").click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>If you click on me, I will disappear.</p>
<p>Click me away!</p>
<p>Click me too!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

above written is the code i am using for testing jquery..

when i run the html file its not working in my browser.

this code runs well in my browser when i run it from w3schools.com.

please let me know what could be the reason for not working of this code.
the java script is enable in my browser.

Comment: Did you try to use a debugger to see what fails?

Comment: *"...jquery code not working..."* *"...the code is perfect..."* Those two statements don't really go together.

Comment: Is your URL address strating with "file:///..." ?

Comment: **EVERYONE**: The script path **is fine** (provided the HTML page isn't being loaded *locally*, e.g. from a `file://` URL). By [leaving off the protocol](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/skipping-protocol.html), the OP is making it work on both an `http` and `https` page. Yes, really.

Comment: script works in latest chrome and ie 8. what browser do you use?

Comment: @earthdesigner: I think that's an *answer*.

Comment: Yes, Really.

Thanks Crowder. Lay down the law :)

Comment: the code was perfect but not working because i was executing the file locally and the http:// was missing in the script path..now it solved i added the http:// in the script path and now its working fine. now the code is working and perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your jQuery path can only work if your file is on the server. If not then use this path:

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js

Answer (score 3):

Your code works as expected.

But. **How are you opening the file?** Through the file-explorer, or are you hosting the file on a local web-server?

The first won't work, the latter will, because of the way you're doing the jQuery script file path. By leaving off the protocol, you make it inherit the protocol of the page. If that's `http` or `https`, that's fine. But if it's `file`, well, you probably don't have a file at that location. So **if** you're loading it locally (e.g., you see `file://` at the beginning of the URL), you need to put a `http:` in front of your script path.

Alternately, if you are looking for an easy to set up webserver on Windows (so you can open the file with a `http` URL and your script path works), I'm fairly happy with [QuickPHP](http://www.zachsaw.com/?pg=quickphp_php_tester_debugger). Linux/Windows/Mac all have lots of options. Just ask Google.

Best of luck!

Comment: Wow. Thanks for the edit, Crowder. I can see where the 165k comes from.

Comment: Thank you phareim.. http:// was missing in the script. it worked locally when i wrote http:// in script path. Thanks to u too crowder.

Comment: @user2034961 no problem. For further development I encourage you to set up some form of web-server locally. - Happy hacking!

Answer (score -2):

The `<script>` source is wrong

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

Comment: yeah the source was wrong i corrected it now..thanks for replying.

Comment: please mark it as answer if you got the right suggestion from the post. Thanks